# git-svn creates a lot of branches appended with @rev

Tags: git, git-svn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [git-svn clone | spurious branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356901/git-svn-clone-spurious-branches)

I converted an SVN repo to git with git-svn.

Everything seems to be fine, but there a lot of branches named `branch-name@rev` (i.e. `remotes/release-1.0@10920`), which are not in SVN.

Does anybody know where they come from?

Comment: May be this are branches/tags which have been deleted in SVN...

Comment: no I'm pretty sure that these branches have never existed in svn

Comment: These are looking more like tags than branches ...so may someone has deleted the tags (you can take a detailed look into svn based on the given revision number).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the only time those kinds of refs show up, but one place where they do show up is when the entire project was moved (renamed) in svn.

Comment: Posted similar issue in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356901/git-svn-clone-spurious-branches. But the reported branches weren't deleted or moved. Even for some of the normal commit revisions, these branches are created. Any idea why this happens ?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem too. Remember to use the `-s` option to tell git that your svn is of a particular standard layout and all should be good.

Comment: where  should I add this option?

Comment: git svn clone -s http://svn.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: retyed with -s flag with same result...