# git-svn clone | spurious branches

Tags: git, git-svn, git-branch

I used the following command to clone svn repo into git and after executing it, i see some spurious branches.

`git svn clone [SVN repo URL] --no-metadata -A authors-transform.txt --stdlayout ~/temp`

`git branch -a`

```
*(no branch)
  master
  remotes/abc-1.3.x
  remotes/abc-1.3.x@113346
  remotes/abc-1.3.x@541512
  remotes/branch_test_script
  remotes/tags/modules-1.2
  remotes/tags/modules-1.2@113346
  remotes/tags/modules-1.2@516265
  remotes/tags/release-1.1
  remotes/tags/release-1.1@113346
  remotes/tags/release-1.1@468862
  remotes/trunk
```

Actual branches created in svn were abc, branch_test_script, modules and release.
Can someone help in understanding what 'abc-1.3.x@113346' , 'abc-1.3.x@541512' ... 'release-1.1@468862' etc are ?

How can we get rid of these spurious branches / what do they signify ?

Thanks,
Gayathri

Comment: I have a really hard time finding where this naming came from, but it looks like these branches are created from SVN commits which were found to be not referenced anymore by the svn branch (or tag) they were originally made on. Like unreferenced commits in Git, except that it was possible to recover the branch name for the commit.

Comment: @fork0 : Thanks for the reply. But i dont understand clearly as to how unreferenced commits can be present in svn. How can references be lost ? Can you share your thoughts on this ?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe the maintainer of the SVN repository never cleaned them up (or SVN doesn't have the ability at all?). I didn't mean to say the references were lost, rather someone just started committing from an earlier point in the history

Comment: Maybe the commit listing in SVN always produce the full listing of all commits, independently of whether they are referenced by a tag or branch

Comment: But some of these branches weren't deleted or moved. Even for some of the normal commit revisions, these branches are created. Any idea why this happens ?

Comment: No idea. Unconnected branches of history is my only explanation

Comment: Similar problem: [git-svn creates duplicate tags with at sign in name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291121/git-svn-creates-duplicate-tags-with-at-sign-in-name)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

tl;dr:

`git svn` creates these "@"-branches if a branch (or tag) was created for a subdirectory (or for another directory which is not tracked by git-svn). There will always also be a "regular" branch with the same name, but without the "@" suffix. The "@"-branch only exists as a branching point for the regular branch.

---

*Note: I submitted a patch for this; an edited version of this explanation is now part of the official `git svn` manpage, as a new section "HANDLING OF SVN BRANCHES" (since Git 1.8.1).*

---

In Subversion, branches and tags are just copies of a directory tree, so it's possible (though usually discouraged) to create a branch from a directory that is not itself a branch (or trunk). For example, by copying /trunk/foo to /branches/bar, instead of copying /trunk (a "subdirectory branch", so to speak), or by copying a directory that lies outside the trunk/tags/branches structure (which is possible in SVN).

In git, however, a branch is always for the whole repo, subdirectory branches do not exist.  `git svn` therefore uses a workaround. If it detects a branch that was copied from a directory that is not itself tracked as a branch by git-svn, it will create a new history. For example,  for a subdirectory branch where /trunk/foo is copied to /branches/bar in r1234, it will create:

- A new git commit for each SVN revision from r1233 on backwards (note the number is the last revision before the branch was created). The trees of these commits will only contain the subdirectory that was branched. So for each revision from r1233 backwards, there will usually be two git commits, one with the whole tree (created when git-svn processed the history of `trunk`), and the new ones.
- A dummy branch called "bar@1233" (branch name@revision), which poinst to the commit created from r1233 above.
- A commit from r1234, the commit that created the branch. This commit will have the branch above as its (only) ancestor.
- A branch called "bar", which points to the second commit.

In that way, for the subdirectory branch bar, you get two branches in git

- bar@1233 , which represents the state of the repository that the branch was created from
- bar, which represents the branch

I'm not quite sure why this dummy branch is created. I think it is done to represent the information about which revision the branch was branched from, and to have a complete history for the branch.

---

Note that this whole mechanism can be switched off by using the flag `--no-follow-parent`. In that case, each SVN branch will result in a git branch with just the commits from the SVN branch directory. Each branch will be unconnnected to the rest of the history, and will have its own root commit, corresponding to the first commit in the branch.

Answer (score 6):

I had such strangely called branches too when I cloned my SVN repo into a Git repo.

After reviewing the expected branches (in your case `modules-1.2`, `abc-1.3.x`, `branch_test_script` and `release-1.1`) I noticed that the `@revisionnumber`branches are nothing else than commits in their prefixed branches.

If you want to do it manually, open `gitk` on branch `abc-1.3.x` and verify that `abc-1.3.x@113346` and `abc-1.3.x@541512` show up in the history of that branch. If so, you could delete the respective branch.

This could be a bit cumbersome if you have many branches or many commits to browse through.

Automatic way: ask git to do it for you:

```
git branch -r --contains abc-1.3.x@113346
```

will echo (or at least **should**)

```
abc-1.3.x
abc-1.3.x@113346
abc-1.3.x@541512
```

This means that you could safely delete `abc-1.3.x@113346` because it's contained in `abc-1.3.x`:

```
git branch -r -d abc-1.3.x@113346
```

Because of the linear history of SVN, it is of course also contained it the (newer) commit `541512`.

---

**Side note:**
You might have noticed that your SVN tags are not actually converted to Git tags and native Git branches. This could be achieved using [svn2git](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git) to clone the SVN repo into a Git repo.

Comment: How to remove these branches ? Is there any parameter that can be passed to git to ignore such commits and not create branches ?

Comment: As I wrote: the branches could be deleted using `git branch -r -d <branchname>`. I don't think that there's a flag to achieve that the branches are not created.

Comment: `git-svn` might possibly create these "@" branches needlessly, but there is an important case where `abc@113346` is **not** ancestor of `abc`. That happens if the branch is deleted in subversion and than created again by copy from another point. Also the fact that `abc@113346` is an ancestor of `abc` does not mean that this didn't happen, it might mean that `abc` was merged to trunk, deleted (in some revision higher than 113346) and a new one created in it's place from trunk.

Comment: In other words no, this answer is **wrong**. The "should" isn't true. It might or might not, depending on whether the branch was merged before it was deleted.